# Can I export an iOS app only with developer and iTunes account?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

This question might not belong to StackOverflow, but I am not sure where else on the StackExchange network should I post it to. I am sorry if that is the case.

I am supposed to work on a project that some colleagues have already started working on. They told me only the apple developer account's username and password, as well as the itunes connect account's username and password.

I tried downloading all of the Provisioning Profiles and Certificates from the developer account, and then adding the Provisioning Profiles to my iPhone Configuration Utility's Library, as well as adding the Certificates in Keychain Acces (I wasn't prompted to enter password for them, I think this might be the issue). I also added the account in the XCode Preferences. Whenever I tried archiving the app, I got this error:

```
No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate 
and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in 
your build settings.
```

I've tried reloading all of the stuff a couple of times, but I can't seem to archive the app so I can distribute it through the AppStore.

What am I doing wrong or am I missing something?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Ask your colleagues to go into Xcode -> preferences -> accounts -->
  export developer account and email it to you, then you can import it
  into your Xcode.
- Go into iTunes Connect, and create a new developer certificate so
  that your computer will have it set up properly (including the
  private key that is probably missing in your current situation).

Also, make sure that:

- Code sign settings in build settings are set properly. AKA, make sure
  the correct developer certificate is chosen and provision profile in
  this case is set to automatically.
- No duplicates of certificates in keychain exist.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out already. The other developer should've exported their certificates instead of me downloading them from the developer account.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the certificates you downloaded from developer account doesn't have its private key associated with it. You better create a new developer profile.